# Design Bug: "Favorite" / "Ignored Tags" textfields are too wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Textfields in Favorite Tags / Ignored Tags edit forms in the sidebar are too wide, so there's an overflow, which hides the buttons partly.

The buttons should move to the next line or made smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed, will be live after our next production build.